# How to properly wait for first completed task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, console-application

I'm writing a simple console application that should make requests to different external sources and return the response from whichever source answers first.

I'm trying to do this using `Task` objects (to keep the code as simple as possible), but my program deadlocks and never completes execution. Now, I suspect that it's because I'm using `Result` on my tasks, but I have no idea how to make it work without the `Result`.

```
public static string GetResultFromAnySource()
{
    var t1 = new Task<string>(() => { Thread.Sleep(500); return "Result from source 1"; });
    var t2 = new Task<string>(() => { Thread.Sleep(100); return "Result from source 2"; });

    var res = Task.WhenAny(t1, t2).Result;

    if (res == t1)
        return "Source 1 was faster. Result: " + t1.Result;
    else if (res == t2)
        return "Source 2 was faster. Result: " + t2.Result;

    throw new ApplicationException("Something went very wrong");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetResultFromAnySource());
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to start the tasks.

```
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
```

Alternatively, use `Task.Run()`

```
var t1 = Task.Run<string>(() => { Thread.Sleep(500); return "Result from source 1"; });
var t2 = Task.Run<string>(() => { Thread.Sleep(100); return "Result from source 2"; });
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi Andre I rewrote your program by using async/await keywords:

```
class Program {
public static async Task<string> GetResultFromAnySource() {

  var t1 = Task<string>.Run( () => {  Task.Delay(500).Wait(); return "Result from source 1"; });
  var t2 = Task<string>.Run(() => { Task.Delay(100).Wait(); return "Result from source 2"; });

  var res = await Task.WhenAny(t1, t2);

  if (res == t1)
    return "Source 1 was faster. Result: " + await t1;
  else if (res == t2)
    return "Source 2 was faster. Result: " + await t2;

  throw new ApplicationException("Something went very wrong");
}

static void Main(string[] args) {

  Task.Run(async () => await Out()).Wait();
}

static async Task Out()
{
  var str = await GetResultFromAnySource();
  Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

}

It is recommended to use Task.Run - the code is clear and it starts the task immediately.

Comment: What is the purpose of this call `Task.Run(async () => await Out()).Wait();`? How is it different form just `Out().Wait();`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understood it: The Task is asynchronous and is run in another Thread. But Wait() blocks this thread as well and forces to wait for the other thread to complete. This might be very good when you're in a background Thread and use the UI Thread via ``Dispatcher.Invoke``. The background thread can wait and the UI thread is only utilized for a very specific short Task and then freed again to do UI things.